# Killing a processes (supposedly) busy in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, signals, process

I accidentally fired off a `mount` on the wrong partition. `sda4` is the *extended partition* containing `sdaX`, *X>4*, whereas I wanted to mount the Fat32 partition `sda7`.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda4 /media/win
```

Now the `mount` is busy since 45min and using 100% CPU time (1 of two cores).

**How can I stop or kill that mount?**

I already tried (it's pid being 10155):

- `kill -TERM 10155` -- and also `KILL`, `USR1`, `USR2`, `INT`, all to no effect
- `kill -STOP 10155` -- I thought this might at least give me some room, but it kept running with 100%
- `renice 20 10155` -- *this at least* got other processes some room to breathe.

Is there maybe something in `/proc` I can use to kill the mount?

**Update:** My Linux is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 64bit. `uname -a`: `Linux ... 3.2.0-27-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 6 14:25:57 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 3.2.0/64bit.

Comment: I don't now, it's may be a bug on the mount syscall, in this link tehy talk about a bug introduced between kernel 3.1 and 3.4 : https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=835019, you're may be in this case. A new patch is availabale here : https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/6/25/306. Hope this help

Comment: @TOC: Thanks for finding that out. I hoped not having to reboot though... *smile*.

Comment: you need maybe to reboot (:, or use something like (kexec or ksplice), i haven't use them before...Good luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **How can I stop or kill that mount?**

You can't; system calls are uninterruptible. You will need to wait until it either times out or errors out, assuming it ever will.

Comment: Thats what I feared. And in kernel-speak "uninterpretable" means "not even Linus" or some "super root tool"?

Comment: It's actually *dangerous* to have a process handle an interrupt while in kernel space since it could result in the handler running in the supervisor ring, leading to all sorts of possible exploits. The process *must* return from the system call before interrupts can be handled.